# How do I map a GraphQL response with a JSON array property in C#?

Tags: c#, graphql

Mapping C# Class to GraphQL Response.

Hi,

I am learning GraphQL and how to query/commuicate with a GraphQL endpoint.  The json response looks like the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allFilms": {
      "films": [
        {
          "title": "A New Hope",
          "releaseDate": "1977-05-25"
        },
        {
          "title": "The Empire Strikes Back",
          "releaseDate": "1980-05-17"
        },
        {
          "title": "Return of the Jedi",
          "releaseDate": "1983-05-25"
        },
        {
          "title": "The Phantom Menace",
          "releaseDate": "1999-05-19"
        },
        {
          "title": "Attack of the Clones",
          "releaseDate": "2002-05-16"
        },
        {
          "title": "Revenge of the Sith",
          "releaseDate": "2005-05-19"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am having a difficult time trying to map my response object accordingly.  This is what I have so far:

```
   public class GraphQLFilmResponse
{
    public allFilms allFilms { get; set; }
}

public class allFilms
{
    public films films { get; set; }
}

public class films
{
    public List<film> film { get; set; }
}

public class film
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? releaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

The error message is as follows:
Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'GraphQL.films' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Any help or links (I am sure someone asked this question already) would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have a class that represents "data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public class Data
{
    public AllFilms AllFilms { get; set; }
}

public class AllFilms
{
    public List<Film> Films { get; set; }
}

public class Film
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize object:

```
option = new JsonSerialiazerOption(){ PropertyNameCaseInsensitivity = true};
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialze<Data>(response, options);
```

Comment: Thank you Bane.  I guess youtube videos only get me so far.  =)  Thank you again.  Works great!!!!